# Change order PDF

Tags: magento-1.7, pdf

I'm trying to chane the `sales > Order` PDF's.
[image]

I know how to edit the invoices (listed below the orders in the screenshot), but not the orders. I know you can change the text in `configuration > Sales` But I need to edit the layout.

I've found a couple of articles that say you should edit `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` but that does not do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on Magento Wiki regarding, how to change the invoice PDF. You can review it. The link of the article is [Magento Wiki - Edit an invoice PDF](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf)

Basically, You will have to goto `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/` all the required PDF files will be found there. Override the files from core to local folder and do the required changes.